# Getting rid of absolute paths in scripts

Tags: python, directory

A typical situation for me is like this:

I have Python script which will during its run, open files from its dir.
In effect it will be something like.

```
actual_script_dir/
        script.py
        config.json
...
(somewhere in filesystem on my python path):
my_utilities/
        module.py
...


#script.py
from my_utilities.module import Config
config_path='config.json'
conf=Config(file_path)
...
```

When I test it, I just usually run the file from its directory:

```
actual_scriptdir$ python3 script.py
```

and everything works.

However, the scripts are meant for crontab, which obviously has different directory when executing (/usr/bin):

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/python3 {actual_script_dir}/script.py
```

In which case I need to change config_path to absolute like:

```
config_path='{actual_script_dir}/config.json'
```

or it wil not be found.

The question is, **can I somehow keep relative file paths in script.py regardless of working directory of execution?** Ideally this would be part of Config module, which would know the actual path of the script it is loaded in.

I tried using `__file__` and `pathlib Path`, but they either need to be used in script.py, which kinda defeats the purpose, or they show the my_utilities_module path, which is obviously not where config.json is located.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you can't use `pathlib.Path` - you've said you want it to be part of the Config logic, but would it be a big disadvantage to have that in the scripts file?  I currently end up with a `THIS_DIR` constant in many of my scripts, which I then extend to find local config files.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with using `__file__` or `Path`. it is standard method to get `THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` in `script.py` and later use `config_path = os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'config.json')` to get absolute path to file.

Comment: @furas Simply to avoid boilerplate. I have by  now done essentially what you suggest, but it is inelegent IMO. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `__file__` with `pathlib.Path` and then pass the full path into `Config`:

```py
#script.py
from pathlib import Path
from my_utilities.module import Config
config_path='config.json'
THIS_DIR = Path(__file__).parent()
conf=Config(THIS_DIR / config_path)
```

I saw you mentioned in your original question that they "[...] need to be used in script.py, which kinda defeats the purpose" but I can't think where the problem might be (as per my comment).

EDIT:
Previous answer was missing `.parent()` which is required for the directory instead of the file.

Comment: I have dozens of scripts in different directories, which all use the same kind config files in their respective dirs. I was specifically trying to avoid adding boilerplate code in every script, that's why I would have wanted Config module to be able to receive THIS_DIR "automagically" somehow,  Sorry if it wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: Besides execing Path(__file__) will give relative path, if execed from commandline. eg. "python3 script.py" will make THIS_DIR be empty string.

Comment: Regarding your point on the relative path, you can get the full path with e.g. `resolve`, i.e. `Config( (THIS_DIR / config_path).resolve() )` . But I'm afraid I don't know how you can avoid putting a `THIS_DIR` line in the script.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't really answer your question, I think it would be more flexible to accept the config path as the script's argument, instead of hard-coding it.

You could then specify both the script's path and the absolute path to the config in the CRON rule:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/python3 {actual_script_dir}/script.py {actual_script_dir}/config.json
```

To read the argument, use `sys.argc` and `sys.argv`, or even better, the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially I ended up passing `__file__` to a special Config function.

```
class Config:
...
   def this_dir(self,calling_file,json_file='config.json'):
      self.script_dir=self.script_dir=os.path.dirname(Path(calling_file).absolute())
      return os.path.join(self.script_dir,json_file)

...

Then, in calling program, I have to do:

conf=Config()
conf.load(conf.this_dir(__file__))
```

Inelegant, but the best I can do to avoid hardcoding paths when execing scripts both by hand and from crontab.

Comment: you have function `this_dir()` which inside class is accesible by `self.this_dir()` - and later you use `self.this_dir = ...` so you replace funtion with string/path - and this can make problem if you will have to run again function `conf.this_dir()`. Frankly, I would create this path outside `Config()` because it can be used also to load other files from the same folder